# Does `Age` have to be used when using `Cache-Control: max-age`?

Tags: http, caching, http-headers, cache-control, response-headers

Quote from [Cache-Control](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control#max-age):

> ##### `max-age`
>
> The `max-age=N` response directive indicates that the response remains fresh until *N* seconds after the response is generated.
>
> ```
> Cache-Control: max-age=604800
> ```
>
> Indicates that caches can store this response and reuse it for subsequent requests while it's fresh.
>
> Note that `max-age` is not the elapsed time since the response was received, but instead the elapsed time since the response was generated on the origin server. ***So if the other cache(s) on the path the response takes store it for 100 seconds (indicated using the `Age` response header field), the browser cache would deduct 100 seconds from its freshness lifetime.*** [emphasis added]
>
> ```
> Cache-Control: max-age=604800
> Age: 100
> ```

If `Age` isn't used when using `Cache-Control: max-age`, can browsers know when the cache is outdated? If they can, how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[RFC 7234](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7234) explains how a cache can [estimate the age of a response message](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7234#section-4.2.3).

Yes, the `Age` header is used, if available:

> The term `"age_value"` denotes the value of the `Age` header field
> (Section 5.1), in a form appropriate for arithmetic operation; or
> 0, if not available.

A response delay is also added to it:

> ```
> response_delay = response_time - request_time;
> corrected_age_value = age_value + response_delay;
> ```

If no `Age` header is present, a cache may approximate it with:

> `apparent_age = max(0, response_time - date_value);`

The cache then uses the largest of the two:

> ```
> corrected_initial_age = max(apparent_age, corrected_age_value);
> ```